# Ionic React IonRadioGroup infinite loop on IonChange

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I get an infinite loop any time I set the value of the radio button group on the component update, I am working on a quiz app it has made me stuck here is my current code, I want a situation where when the user has already solved a quiz question the answer should be already selected on navigating to the question

```
xport default class SubjectQuiz extends React.Component <IProps, IState>{

  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { userSelectedAnswers:[], score: 0,curNum:0,
      quizOver:false,
      Questions:this.props.Question,
      selected:'',
      currentSelectedIndex:{questionNumber:0,
        option:'',
        //index:string|number,
        answerIsCorrect:false,
        answer:''}};
   

  }
componentDidUpdate(){
      
      
      var i = this.state.userSelectedAnswers.findIndex(o => o.questionNumber === this.state.curNum);
      console.log("the value of question index in array "+i);
      
      if(i==-1){
        
        this.setState({selected:'F'})
      }else{

        
        this.setState({selected:this.state.userSelectedAnswers[i].correctAnswerOption})


     
    }


  }
```

here is the Tsx

```
<IonRadioGroup value={this.state.selected}  onIonChange={e=>{

          this.setState({selected:e.detail.value})
         this.answerSelected(this.state.selected);


          console.log("here is the selected answer "+JSON.stringify(e.detail));
          
          
      }}> 

       <IonList>
      

        <IonItem>
         <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.parseHtmlString(this.state.Questions[this.state.curNum].option_a,this.ImageUrl).outerHTML}}></p>
          <IonRadio slot="start" value="A"   />
        </IonItem>

        <IonItem>
         <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.parseHtmlString(this.state.Questions[this.state.curNum].option_b,this.ImageUrl).outerHTML}}></p>
          <IonRadio slot="start" value="B" />
        </IonItem>

        <IonItem>
         <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.parseHtmlString(this.state.Questions[this.state.curNum].option_c,this.ImageUrl).outerHTML}}></p>
          <IonRadio slot="start" value="C" />
        </IonItem>

        <IonItem>
          <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.parseHtmlString(this.state.Questions[this.state.curNum].option_d,this.ImageUrl).outerHTML}}></p>
          <IonRadio slot="start" value="D" />
        </IonItem>

        {this.state.Questions[this.state.curNum].option_e?
        <IonItem>
          <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.parseHtmlString(this.state.Questions[this.state.curNum].option_e,this.ImageUrl).outerHTML}}></p>
          <IonRadio slot="start" value="E" />
        </IonItem>:null}
        <IonRadio slot="start" value="F" defaultChecked={true} hidden={true} />
        </IonList>
        
      </IonRadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) for preventing infinite loop you should compare prevState with current state then make changes:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.state.selected!== prevState.selected) {
    var i = this.state.userSelectedAnswers.findIndex(o => o.questionNumber === this.state.curNum);
    console.log("the value of question index in array " + i);
    if (i == -1) {
      this.setState({ selected: 'F' })
    } else {
      this.setState({ selected: this.state.userSelectedAnswers[i].correctAnswerOption })
    }
  }
}
```